# Inverse of a product of a regular matrix and a matrix with linearly independent rows

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-rank

I got to a point within an exercise, where I would like the following matrix to be invertible:
$$ \mathbf{AC}^{-1}\mathbf{A}^T,$$
where $\mathbf{C}$ is a regular matrix and $\mathbf{A}$ has linearly independent rows (i. e. $\mathbf{AA}^T$ is regular).

The solution contains this matrix, but I don't see why it holds.

Comment: What are the dimensions of those matrices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $A$ has linearly independent rows, it is impossible to find a non-zero vector $v$ such that $A^Tv=0$, since $AA^T$ is invertible. By defining $w=A^Tv$ we obtain $$v^TAC^{-1}A^Tv=w^TC^{-1}w$$ which is again non-zero since $C^{-1}$ is invertible. Hence the result.